# No projects are found to import - Helios eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, helios

When downloading the 64 bit for Helios eclipse claims that there are no projects found to import - the file is swt-3.6-win32-win32-x86_64.zip

This should be fairly straight forward!!!!

Comment: Could you clarify your question? I don't know what and how would you download and import.

Answer (score 2):

On top of what Joe said:

The build path page is located in Properties (right click on project) -> Java Build Path. You can find the Libraries tab there.

I'd add one more step to the aforementioned workaround:

1) Extract the swt-3.6-win32-win32-x86.zip file *(or another version, whichever you need)*
2) The extracted folder contains 2 jar files swt.jar and swt-debug.jar
3) On the Java build path page of your project, open the Libraries tab. And add the swt.jar as an external jar.
**4)** Expand swt.jar on this tab, double click "Source attachment" and point to the archive named swt.zip (also comes in the top-level SWT archive), so that the javadoc will also be available for you.

And that's it - SWT should work like a charm from now on. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug report on this: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=318680

I tried the recommended workaround (included below), but could not find the build path page, nor the Libraries tab, referenced in the workaround.

Instead, I right-clicked on the HelloWorldSWT package (in the Package Explorer window), selected Build Path -> Add External Libraries, and selected the jar file swt.jar. As the tutorial warns, there were compile errors, so I selected Source -> Organize Imports. The program now compiles and runs, but does not do anything. Inserting System.out.println() statements shows that it dies in creating the new Display().

I don't know if this helps [anyone], but I figured I'd share what I've tried so far. If anyone has any suggestions, they would be welcome.

For reference, in case it matters, I'm running Eclipse Helios (3.6) on Mac OS X (64-bit).

Here's the aforementioned workaround:

Lakshmi Shanmugam      2010-07-02 11:16:01 EDT

The step to import the SWT project from the zip is no longer valid. The
cheatsheet needs to be updated.

Please follow the below steps:
1) Extract the swt-3.6-win32-win32-x86.zip file
2) The extracted folder contains 2 jar files swt.jar and swt-debug.jar
3) On the Java build path page of your project, open the Libraries tab. And add
the swt.jar as an external jar.

Answer (score 0):

Can't confirm - I just downloaded said file from the [download page](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.6-201006080911/index.php#SWT) with no problem.

Importing projects is a workbench activity and not related to the eclipse installation process. Try a fresh install of a full 64Bit platform (one of the distributions from eclipse.org).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.  There are instructions in the SWT HelloWorld tutorial linked from the Helios welcome page that instruct the user to first import the SWT project using File > Import ... then selecting Existing Projects into Workspace.  When you specify the SWT archive, you get the error mentioned above "no projects found to import"

I think the problem is that the tutorial needs to be updated to reflect the fact that this archive is not an eclipse project and so cannot be imported in this fashion.
While it cannot be imported as a project, the jar can be linked; or, the source files can be turned into an eclipse project and the otherwise erroneous instructions can be followed from there.