# Cannot import phonegap project after creating android project

Tags: android, cordova

The phonegap create still makes a phonegap project but the eclipse no cannot see projects when you select import and browse to the folder. It says "No projects are found to import".

It worked fine before though because made projects before.

Why does this happen?

UPDATE:

Seems the problem is with my eclipse since tried to give the created phonegap project to a colleague and it is recognized in his eclipse. For some reason my eclipse stopped recognizing phonegap projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@jhdj  Delete all the existing projects in the eclipse ide and import the project which you want i hope you will get it,

file->import->android->existing android code into workspace

hope this works,b/c it worked for me.

You can try.

Comment: Well did something similar but used new->project->android project from existing code. Checked out yours work too, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check are you trying to import from the right directory. You are looking in some wrong
directory.

There are so many posts available in So only for this kind of problem refer them.

[No projects found to import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257036/no-projects-found-to-import)

[No projects are found to import - Helios eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496480/no-projects-are-found-to-import-helios-eclipse)

[Why "no projects found to import"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638016/why-no-projects-found-to-import)

**You also have an alternative which I was using when I was working on linux fedora.**

Otherwise look into this tutorial to build phonegap application in eclipse itself

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/getting-started-with-phonegap-in-eclipse-for-android.html

**See this section** -- Creating the project in Eclipse

The tutorial is for the  cordova-1.5.0.js version.

You can use the latest version or may the versuion you wan to use there is no problem in doing that at all.

Comment: yes I am importing right directory since it is the one that I make when you use create in phonegap in the command prompt, I actually follow the turorial in http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android

Comment: @jhdj You can follow the tutorials for creating phonegap project in eclipse itself.

Comment: That tutorial is still on cordova 1.5.0 though I am currently using 2.5.0

Comment: @jhdj So use the cordova 2.5.0. You have to just use the js files for 2.5.0.

Comment: Will try this if all else fails but was hoping to find a solution that will make the creating of phonegap with the create command work again, since it worked fine before.

Comment: @jhdj I have already working with this strategy with version 2.3.0 and It will work because only the version of js file changing and a class will be changing into your main activity nothing else